# Python & Typer - Project structure and storing option values as an object

Tags: python, typer

I currently have two interesting issues within a python package I am working on.

Considerations

I am using:

- Poetry
- Typer
- Python 3.8.12

Issue Summary

1. Using Typer, I need to pass an input from an option from the CLI into another module for use as a configuration parameter
2. I would need this to be passed before other upstream modules ran. I would also need to resolve the circular import that doing this would cause

Issue Diagram

[image]

Issue #1 details:

I have the following class and function within the main.py module

```
@dataclass
class Common:
    profile_dir: str

@app.callback()
def profile_callback(ctx: typer.Context,
                     profile_dir: str = typer.Option(..., )):

    typer.echo(f"Hello {profile_dir}")

    test_dir = {profile_dir}

    """Common Entry Point"""
    ctx.obj = Common(profile_dir)

    return (test_dir)
```

The option works well when just echoing the CLI option but I have issues returning the {profile_dir} variable outside of the CLI. Typer only seems to be able to echo the variable, not store it. I am struggling to reference {profile_dir} outside of the CLI and outside the function.

What I would like to be able to do is turn {profile_dir} into an object that I can reference outside of the function and that I can pass from main.py into config.py

Issue #2

If I were to resolve issue #1, I would then encountered issue#2. As the CLI commands exist within the module_#_cli.py files and the main.py file, they import from the config.py upstream. This would lead me to the following error:

```
cannot import name 'cli_profile_path' from partially initialized module 'example.main' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'm pretty dumbfounded about how to resolve this as the package would import config parameters from the config.py module when there is no CLI option. I have struggled to think of a way to pass config parameters from the CLI into the config.py classes to then be used within the intermediary modules without the counterintuitive flow within the diagram.